# Using Selenium in Java to download a file in Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using `Selenium WebDriver` to automate a webpage. When I click 'download' on one of the pages it opens a small pop-up (it's not a new/different window) and I cannot perform an "inspect element" on that window. Due to this, I'm unable to gain access to that pop-up page and control it. Is there a solution to this problem using `Selenium` or something else in `Java`?

Comment: This question is already answered here [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510816/how-to-handle-downloading-a-file-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I already tried that solution and added it to my code but it is still unable to download the file directly. I have added a screenshot of the "do you want to download pane" along with. Sorry, i cannot attach a screen shot along with as I need to have reputation greater than 10.

Comment: It's not a new pop up window but a javascript pop up due to which i cannot do "Inspect Element" for that pane. The pop up window offers the option to "Save file" or "Open with" and there is a check box which offers me to automatically download the file the next time without asking this prompt.

Comment: I was pointing you to the firefox profile settings that you can do to avoid that pop up. it will directly download that file to the given location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle downloading a file in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510816/how-to-handle-downloading-a-file-in-selenium-webdriver)